# Как написать скрипт, отключающий интернет на определенное время?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7, командная-строка

Скрипт должен работать на Windows 7.

Алгоритм такой:

1. Отключение интернета адаптеров `Wi-Fi` и `Ethernet`.
2. Ожидание определенное количество времени.
3. Включение интернета.

Comment: А кто должен давать скрипту разрешение на повышение привилегий? чтобы выполнитьотключение устройства, пользователь должен быть администратором. И при дефолтных установках UAC его всё равно переспросят. Проблема XY?

Comment: Эмм, меня всё устраивает, мой юзер админ

Comment: типа последовательности команд: **wmic nicconfig where ipenabled="true" get index**, **wmic nicconfig where index="%index%" call disable**, **choice /d Y /t %timeout%**, **wmic nicconfig where index="%index%" call enable**